# Screen reader reads flash in Google's Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, accessibility, screen-readers

The screen reader (JAWS) is able to read the textfield in Flash on Google's Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 8. I'm using the latest version of `SWFobject`.

Answer (score 1):

Flash support in Jaws for windows sucks, don't rely on it if you have to make your site accessible. I'm blind and have used Jaws for the passed 10 years and have never run across a flash application that worked even moderately well. It's nice that jaws can read flash labels in Chrome, now all they need to do is read the rest of the content like the rendered html.